# How to change the font size of the list (not the initial view)

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have set a custom font and background for the initial view of the dropdown list (Select a choice). The `font-size` is 20 pixels and looks great with the custom font. However when I click on the list, the options themselves do not use the custom font and look normal, except for the `font-size`, which seems to carry over. This only seems to be the case with Chrome (I've tested Safari and Firefox as well).

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Averia Libre';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Averia Libre Regular'), local('AveriaLibre-Regular'),
    url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/averialibre/v1/rYVgHZZQICWnhjguGsBspHhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff') format('woff');
}
select {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Averia Libre', cursive;
    background: url(http://www.greenriverworks.com/elements/borders/green_button_background_over.jpg) repeat-x;
    width: 400px;
    font-family: 'Averia Libre';
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Averia+Libre' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<select>
    <option value="">I'm a custom font.</option>
    <option value="">Hey me too!</option>
    <option value="">Averia Libre</option>
</select>
```

I tried creating a separate class for the options themselves, but that did not seem to have any effect.

To illustrate further, here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bumpy009/wpHKe/7).

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

Comment: can you include a bit of css to help answer this please.

Comment: @trickeedickee http://jsfiddle.net/bumpy009/wpHKe/7/

Comment: This is really weird. So far it works fine for three people that are reviewing your problem, the problem might be in you somehow. But I've no idea why. Would love to hear if anyone else does not see the custom font.

Comment: I'm no a mac... That could be it.

Answer (score 6):

I am agreed with Peter but by the use of:

```
select {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Averia Libre', cursive;
}
```

on the css will change all of the dropdown font so he should use class instead of total select

CSS

```
.selectClass {
   font-size: 25px;
   font-family: 'Impact', cursive;
}​
```

And HTML

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Averia+Libre' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<select class="selectClass">
<option value="">I'm a custom font.</option>
<option value="">Hey me too!</option>
<option value="">Averia Libre</option>
</select>​
```

Or you may see the fiddle directly on
http://jsfiddle.net/sNkDW/

Comment: Thank you for the remark, but this is **demo** for a reason. Such small details and clarifications aren't worth of a complete new post.

Comment: In the actual code I did use a class. I don't see the custom font in your jsfiddle either.

Comment: @domino, you can use any font. I just put an example of font "impact"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the the dropdown list is being rendering by the "native UI" of Mac OS X.

If setting the font and/or size doesn't actually change anything, there's nothing you can do about it.

(Other than replacing the `<select>` with a [custom JavaScript version](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)).

Comment: The font size does change, but it shouldn't affect the list itself. In chrome it does. I'll look into the js version, thanks.

Comment: Maybe it shouldn't affect the list itself, but unfortunately there's no way to change it :( *(other than using a JavaScript replacement)*

Answer (score 2):

In chrome try adding `background: white;` to the class Select. By setting the background to white Chrome also followed the rest of my specifications such as height and font.

```
.yourselectclass select {
    background: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
    height: 30px;
    width: 88px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done this successfully on Chrome. Here's an example with custom font by Google Fonts.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/simple/wpHKe/

The **HTML** code, as yours:

```
<select>
<option value="">I'm a custom font.</option>
<option value="">Hey me too!</option>
<option value="">Averia Libre</option>
</select>​
```

**Of course, CSS:**

```
select {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Averia Libre', cursive;
}​
```

**And the Font Face that comes from Google:**

You can see this one linked as an external style sheet, but this is the code inside it.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Averia Libre';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Averia Libre Regular'), local('AveriaLibre-Regular'),
  url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/averialibre/v1/rYVgHZZQICWnhjguGsBspHhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff') format('woff');
}
```

**Edit:**

As pointed out by **@Jhilom**, if you don't want this to affect all DropdDowns on your site, be sure to include a CSS Class to the Select, like so:

HTML:

```
<select class="yourSelectClass">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.yourSelectClass
{
/* Your Dropdown CSS here */
}
```

Comment: I edited your code a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/bumpy009/wpHKe/7/  It does look big in chrome...

Comment: The actual dropdown did have a class.

Comment: You're not testing on a Mac, are you?

Answer (score 0):

The CSS styling of the text inside the option tags cannot be changed in Firefox.

In Firefox:
Only the "selected" element in the drop down combo box respects any CSS styling you apply. The style does not cascade down to the option tags. Adding CSS style to each option tag has no effect.

In Chrome:
Chrome respects the CSS styling you add to the select and option tags. The style does not cascade down from the select tag to the option tags, but you can apply style to each option tag.

I've read that "the standard" does not require the select and option tags to be stylable.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. Actually its not an issue. The select menu size appears based on the **list item text length**. Check your option label

Ex: If you have lengthy text in the option tags then the select menu font size will be small.