# Burmese characters not displaying in drop down mvc C#

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to display Burmese/Myanmar character on my website. I have downloaded the fonts and installed them. The characters are displaying correctly on the html-text section of the pages. But the characters are not getting displayed in the drop down. I only see boxes in the dropdown. The text is not appearing in browsers, IE and FF. It is appearing correctly in Chrome. The website is developed using MVC 4 and C#.

I have tried the following possible combinations. The txt contains Burmese string read from the database.

```
lst.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(txt), Value = Id });

WebUtility.HtmlDecode(txt);
Server.HtmlDecode(txt);
Server.HtmlEncode(txt);
MvcHtmlString.Create(txt).ToHtmlString();
MvcHtmlString.Create(txt).ToString();

In the View, I am calling the dropdown

  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.txt, Model.lst, null, new {Id = "idDdl" })

Using utf-8 encoding  <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Please can anyone tell me why the characters are not appearing for Burmese only in the drop down for IE or FF and how I should fix this issue. The text for various other international languages such as Chinese, Spanish, French, Somali are appearing correctly in the dropdown.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: May be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696004/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542576/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525375/

Comment: Had visited those links before, the fiddle example did not work in IE. Didn't think it was a css issue, since just wanted to display words and not any font styles.Tried the css:   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.txt, Model.lst, null, new {Id = "idDdl", class="select-options" }) <style>  .select-option {font-family: Myanmar3, 'Win Innwa', 'Arial Unicode MS', Verdana, Arial;} </style>. I got it working for FF but still didn't work for IE.Since IE doesn't allow styling of drpdown options, I guess will need to replace it with some jquery plugin. Hopefully that should work. Thanks for the direction...