# How to change the size of the font in this drop list script

Tags: fonts, size

I have no knowledge of HTML but the script below seems to work for what I am doing. I just need someone to tell me how can I change the size of the font in this drop down list script. It works great except I would want to change the size of the font. Any Help would be appreciated

```
<select>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select Destination</option>
    <option value="1">Bathroom</option>
    <option value="2">Main Office</option>
    <option value="3">Counselor</option>
    <option value="4">New Bldg.</option>
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [dropdown css - how to change the font size or the list (not the initial view) - CHROME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542576/dropdown-css-how-to-change-the-font-size-or-the-list-not-the-initial-view)

Comment: I have no idea what you just said   Do i have to add something else to the script . so I can change the size of the font.

Comment: Just add a style attribute to the list. For example: 

font-size: 22px;